# cffile read get explicit html

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to create a DIY HTML editor for a project. So far I've managed to create files and edit the content in them. However, when re-reading the file, I can't seem to find a way to read the file and output `<p>Test</p>` rather than `Test` because by default the browser will obviously read the HTML tags. Is there a way of doing it where I can display EVERYTHING contained in the document without it performing the script or reading the HTML? (I know, tricky question)

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you on?

Comment: ColdFusion 10, i'm just seeing if i can justify spending time creating a custom in-house html + server variable editor.. I believe with a bit of care + attention i can make something.

Comment: No worries. It's just the answer (no posted) differs depending on your CF version. It's always best to tag your question with the appropriate CF version.

Comment: I'll remember that in future, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

On ColdFusion 10, the best approach would be to use [`encodeForHtml()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WS932f2e4c7c04df8f-6f7941141353e2963af-7fff.html), I think.

[`htmlEditFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7847.html) is an old school option which does not escape things as well as the former suggestion does. There is also [`htmlCodeFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7848.html), but that is specifically for formatting *code*, hence the name, so it preserves indentation and wraps the result in `<PRE>` tags (and - yes - it's in all caps. Bleah). Odd how it doesn't wrap something that's supposedly "code" in `<code>` tags to preserve the semantics of the text. Not to worry.

Anyway, `encodeForHtml()` is the way to go on CF10, I reckon.

If you *need* to preserve the indentation, then I'd still use `encodeForHtml()` and manually wrap it in `<pre>` and `<code>` tags, rather than use `htmlCodeFormat()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your variable in the [`htmlcodeformat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7848.html) function:

```
<Cfset testFile="<p>Test</p>">


<cfoutput>
#htmlcodeformat(testFile)#
</cfoutput>
```